# Unable to assign in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to square even index values in numpy array and assign same in that array. I followed 2 approaches.

1 -

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
        if i %2 == 0:
            arr[i] = arr[i]**2
```

That is working.

2 -

```
arr[i] = arr[i]**2 for i in range(len(arr)) if i % 2 == 0

 File "<ipython-input-149-30fc7ed25f1f>", line 1
    arr[i] = arr[i]**2 for i in range(len(arr)) if i % 2 == 0
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

not working.

Is some syntax error?

Comment: Don't loop over a numpy array, you lose the power of the optimized code. Rather use np.where - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This works with list compreension:

```
arr = [arr[i]**2 if i % 2 == 0 else arr[i] for i in range(len(arr))]
```

But you could also use the shorter:

```
arr[::2] = arr[::2]**2
```

Comment: `arr[::2] = arr[::2]**2` is by far the best and mosty numpy-style solution of all solutions!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to do [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), for which your syntax is slightly off, read up on the syntax of list comprehension.
It's syntax is similar to `[exp1(item) if condition1 else exp2(item) for item in arr]` .
The correct way to do it is as follows.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr = [arr[i]**2 if i % 2 == 0 else arr[i] for i in range(len(arr))]
print(arr)
#[1, 2, 9, 4, 25, 6]
```

What this is doing is running the for loop, checking the condition, and then picking either `arr[i]` or `arr[i]**2`, and then assigning the result to the list

Comment: This is not a numpy solution?

Comment: Nowhere has the OP use numpy in his code! So I provided a generic solution

Comment: True, but he specifically mentions just before the code that he is using a numpy array...

Answer (score 0):

Dont loop over numpy arrays you lose all the power of numpy.

Use these numpy functions to achieve the required result instead:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(0,10, size=(10,))
print(arr)
ans = np.where(np.arange(10) % 2 == 0, arr, arr**2)
print(ans)
```

output:

```
[ 1 9   1  1  0 6   5  2  1 5 ]
[ 1 81  1  1  0 36  5  4  1 25]
```

np.where selects the elements where the condition is true. Then outputs either the original array or the squared array.

Docs for [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).